# Как обратиться к соседним UserControl'ам

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется `UserControl` uc1 и uc2, оба находятся внутри другого контрола. Необходимо по клику на uc1 воспроизвести `uc2.Enabled = true;`, при этом контролы друг другу являются "братьями" с общим "родителем".

Примечание: Без делегатов и ивентов желательно.

Comment: А почему без ивентов? Они базовая часть языка, причём далеко не самая сложная. И как вы узнаете об изменении состояния без ивентов? (В WPF для похожих целей есть `Binding`, наверное, есть аналоги и под WinForms.)

Comment: Потому что я программирую по-стольку по-скольку и мне сложно их понять. Мне товарищ попытался объяснить ивенты и делегаты, но что-то не получается. Мой код топорен донельзя и строится на глобальных переменных и функциях, запускающих нужные процессы и для того результата, который я хочу получить этого более чем достаточно.

Comment: «Не стыдно быть _чайником_, стыдно не хотеть выйти из этого состояния» (ц) серия книг _для чайников_

Comment: Я то хочу выйти из этого состояния, но всегда есть две стороны медали. И в данный момент усваивать новые методы и усложнять код для меня хуже, чем написать понятным и простым кодом. А потом уже, когда готовый продукт будет работать, можно будет заняться его усовершенствованием.

Comment: Правда в том, что продвинутая функциональность языка нужна для существенного *упрощения* кода и *облегчения* процесса его написания. Я бы посоветовал не пожалеть времени и инвестировать в собственные знания: это окупится очень быстро.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена следующим образом, если не использовать делегаты и ивенты.
Был создан класс, куда были занесены отдельные глобальные переменные под необходимые контролы, к которым нужно было обращаться из сосдених контролов.

```
class C {
    public static uc1 ucc1;
    public static uc2 ucc2;
    public static uc3 ucc3;
}
```

Затем в нужных контролах были созданы записи в эти переменные

```
    public uc1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        C.ucc1 = this;
    }
```

После чего к данному контролу можно обращаться из любого места путем `C.ucc1`.